# Should I say two rakat or four rakat salat before faraz salat?

Tags: salat, sunnah

I am from Bangladesh, generally in our country we perform four rakat salat (Sunnah) before Faraz salat at Zohr, Asar and Isah, but at Macca they performed only two rakat sunnah.

Why is that so? Is there any problem if we perform four rakat sunnah?

Answer (score 1):

Below are some hadiths regarding the optional rakahs before the Asr prayer:

1. > Ali (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the Prophet used to pray four rakahs before the Asr, ending each two rakahs with a tasleem for angels, prophets, and the believers.
   > (An-Nawawi, Al-Majmu`)
2. > Ibn Umar (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the Prophet said, "May Allah shower His mercy on the person who prays four rakahs before the Asr Prayer".
   > (Abu Dawud and At-Tirmidhi)
3. > Ali (RA) reported that the Prophet(PBUH) used to pray two rakahs before the Asr.
   > (Abu Dawud)

In short, according to scholars, you can pray 2+2 rakahs.

Below is the link. Hope its helpful!

http://www.onislam.net/english/ask-the-scholar/acts-of-worship/prayer/supererogatory-prayers/448925-sunnah-befireasr-prayer.html